# How to change the name of a Kotlin property to match the field to on Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I want to change the name of the field that a Kotlin property is pointing to on Firebase database.

For instance:

I have the property count in Kotlin

```
var count: Int
```

But the name on Firebase is **items_count**.
I've already tried using: when I try using

```
@PropertyName("items_count")
var count: Int
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

I achieved it using:

```
@set:PropertyName("items_count")
@get:PropertyName("items_count")
var count: Int
```